# How to activate vibration on call connection

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

I bought lyf water f1 phone at that time vibration on call connection was working by default. But now suddenly it is stopped .I don't know why I want to restart it again same feature could anyone help me regarding this . Os is marshmallow

Answer (score 0):

go to **Settings->Sound->(enable)Also vibrate for calls(Option)**